# How to import a DB with data to the new Laravel DB?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm importing an SQL script from the Laravel command, the theme I don't know how to do for the data extraction since they are not the same attributes that the new database has.

At the moment I have been able to open and read the file but I can't think of how to get the data out. I thought of doing a seeder but the file also brings me the creation of tables.

At the moment this is what I have in code

```
$db = $this->argument('db');
        echo "Reading database from: $db \n";
        echo "\n validating extension \n";
        
        if (!preg_match('/(.*\.)(sql)$/',$db)) {
            echo "Format not valid \n";
            return;
        }

        echo "\n open script \n";
        $data = fopen('C:/sites/'.$db,"rb");
        $content = stream_get_contents($data);

        $output = ImportSQL::remove_comments($content);

        print_r($output);
        exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion would be to import your SQL file into some database and then play with it.

The below code is to write SQL file into same database.

```
$sql = file_get_contents('database_file.sql');
\DB::unprepared($sql);
```

You can create a temporary database for this purpose in `config/database.php` and then use the connection config like:

```
\DB::connection('mysql2')->unprepared($sql);
```